# Find an element inside another using react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

In my react js application, testing the application using react testing library, i have the next situation. I try to find the data from `const d = utils.getAllByTestId('el')[0]`, and now i want to test if inside `d` exists an element that has a `role`: `const i = d.getByRole('img')`, but i get `d.getByRole is not a function`. From the documentation i got that `getByRole` method could be attached only using on the element that is using `render()` method, but i did not find something that could solve my issue. 
 Question: How to achieve what i describe above in react testing library?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

React Testing Library's [`within`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-within/) API can be used to query the nested element.

```
const d = utils.getAllByTestId('el')[0]
const i = within(d).getByRole('img')
```